# Is it possible to use proxy only when a specific profile is active in Maven?

Tags: maven, proxy, maven-3, maven-profiles

I would like to use proxy only when a specific profile is active. To accomplish this, my guess is to parameterize the `<active>` property of `<proxy>` element. However, I am not exactly sure how to accomplish this.

**Question**: How can I use proxy only when a specific profile is active?

Comment: In the _settings.xml_ file, proxies are out of the profiles element, so this will not be possible (see here: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies)

Comment: what might help: you can specify the settings.xml that maven uses with mvn -s /path/to/settings.xml - so having two configurations may possible for your case?

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the original question, which asks about control-by-profile, but one workaround is to ignore `settings.xml` proxies and set `MAVEN_OPTS` when you need to activate a proxy:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=my-proxy-server -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.my.org -Dhttps.proxyHost=my-proxy-server -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=*.my.org"
```

Answer (score 1):

With

https://github.com/volkertb/autoproxy-maven-plugin/

or

https://github.com/c-a-services/overwrite-proxy-setting-plugin

you can set/clear the proxy during a later build phase.

(settings.xml `<proxy>` setting is not designed by maven to be dynamic with properties as property resolving happens after reading user settings.xml)